# Combining and Filtering duplicates of multiple arrays in Template Literal?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am returning product categories based on search results, and I want to list all product categories as one single list with duplicates filtered out. Currently, I'm returning something like:

```
item.productCategories
```

which returns a string of URLS, like so:

```
"<a href=\"https://test.local/product-category/guitar-pickups/\" rel=\"tag\">Guitar Pickups</a>, <a href=\"https://test.local/product-category/hum-cancelling/\" rel=\"tag\">Hum-Cancelling Pickups</a>
```

I'm then splitting them using `.split(",")` and the following expression below to list them in a template literal:

```js
`<ul> ${results["products"].map((item) => `
    <li class="search-result">${item.productCategories
                  .split(",")
                  .map((category) => `<li>${category}</li>`)
                  .join("")}
    </li>`)}
 </ul>`
```

### Result:

I'm getting separate lists of categories like so:

List 1:

- Category 1
- Category 3
- Category 2

List 2:

- Category 1
- Category 2

I'd like to flatten all of these arrays, combine them into one array and then filter out duplicates and return a single array. I do not know where to start with doing this in a Template Literal. Any ideas?

---

### Update:

Thanks to @Bergi I am now able to reduce all links into a new array, but I'm stuck deduplicating the array.

Updated Code:

```
  <ul>${results.products.flatMap((item) => item.productCategories.split(", "))}</ul>
```

I tried   `<ul>${results.products.flatMap((item) => item.productCategories.split(", ")).map((cat) => console.log([...new Set(cat)]))}</ul>` but that blows the individual strings within the array into sub arrays

I'm sorry, I'm new at Array methods. Any help is appreciated.

---

Comment: What does this have to do with template literals? Do you know how to do it if you had used plain string concatenation?

Comment: "*I'm getting separate lists of categories*" - please post the code that produces multiple lists. In the code snippet you've shown so far, only a single list (weirdly, inside a `<li class="search-result">` not an `<ul>`) is generated.

Comment: Edited to show full expression.

Comment: Use `results.products.flatMap(item => item.productCategories.split(', '))`. Then [deduplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1960473/1048572) that and then put it into your template.

Comment: I just updated my code again, If you could offer some assistance, I'd appreciate it, I'm stuck on this one. Thanks, Bergi.

Comment: `flatMap` returns the array that you need to pass into the `new Set`, do not `map()` there. Maybe try not do put everything in a single expression but use some helper variables, and do some debugging on the temporary values

Answer (score 1):

I would use a fragment and spread it into an array you can search and filter

```js
const str = "<a href=\"https://test.local/product-category/guitar-pickups/\" rel=\"tag\">Guitar Pickups</a>, <a href=\"https://test.local/product-category/hum-cancelling/\" rel=\"tag\">Hum-Cancelling Pickups</a>"

const fragment = document.createElement("div");
fragment.innerHTML = str;

const links = fragment.querySelectorAll("a");

console.log([...links])

const hrefs = [...links].map(lnk => lnk.href)
console.log(hrefs)
```